# Cannot submit valid form in FormFunction

Tags: wolfram-cloud, networking, api, applicationserver, http-functions

I have a simple `FormFunction` like this:

```
FormFunction[{"expr" -> ToExpression}, HTTPRequestData[] &]
```

When I use [`CloudDeploy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudDeploy.html), it works as normal. But when I use [`SocketListen`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SocketListen.html) and [`GenerateHTTPResponse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenerateHTTPResponse.html) to establish a server, my Chrome seems have submitted no data as I can't Find it in the results of HTTPRequestData.

I've tried remote server(instead of local), [`GenerateHTTPResponse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GenerateHTTPResponse.html)(instead of any really existing server), `#expr &`(instead of `HTTPRequestData[] &`), none of them works. If I use [`APIFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/APIFunction.html) as the backend and [`URLRead`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/URLRead.html) as the client, everything is OK.

What's missing for the submission compared to the WolframCloud one?

---

Here I provide a minimal server code. When I run this code on my VPS and click the submit button on my Chrome, nothing was submitted in fact.

```
#!/usr/bin/env wolframscript
Respond[socketMsg_Association] := Module[
        {
                client = socketMsg["SourceSocket"],
                data = socketMsg["Data"],
                request,
                response
        },
        request = ImportString[data, "HTTPRequest"];
        response = GenerateHTTPResponse[
                URLDispatcher@{"" -> EvaluationService}
        , request];
        WriteString[
                client,
                ExportString[response, "HTTPResponse"]
        ];
        Close@client
]
EvaluationService = FormFunction[
        {"expr" -> <|"Interpreter" -> ToExpression, "Required"->False|>},
        #expr &
];
SocketListen[{"0.0.0.0",8080},Respond]
Print@"Running..."
TaskWait@ZeroMQLink`Private`$AsyncState["Task"]
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the form?

Comment: @kickert I just want to evaluate expressions via internet explorer etc..

Comment: @Kuba I've updated this question with a server code. The `ToExpression` usage is documented, here's a link: [FormObject](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormObject.html). In the "Details and Options", there's a `tfun` item listed below "Possible forms of type specifications are"

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I was looking at `Interpreter` docs. btw, it boils down to the fact that `HTTPRequest[...]["FormRules"]` returns `None`. You could use this patch: `requestFormRules = 
 Rule @@@ Partition[#, 2] &@URLDecode@StringSplit[#, {"&", "="}] &@
   StringTrim@FromCharacterCode[#["BodyBytes"], "UTF-8"] &` but I am not sure how to apply it.

Comment: @Kuba This command can be effective if it works independently, I have a similar code written before. However, it's still confusing why `FormFunction` ignores submitted body data. I may go for the source code of `GenerateHTTPResponse` and `FormFunction` in the future.

Comment: It does not work because of HttpRequest generated from ImportString. Form values are missing even though they are in the body. I already reported this.

Comment: @Kuba Oh, I see. I didn't check the raw socket data. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Kuba had commented, `ImportString[#, "HTTPRequest"]&` does not turn POST parameters to rules. So the property `"FormRules"`, which `FormFunction` utilizes, can't be generated.

Here is a function to finish this convertion when needed:

```
MakeFormRules[request_HTTPRequest] := With[
    {
        makeFormRules = <|
            URLQueryDecode@StringTrim@FromCharacterCode[#, "UTF-8"]&
    },
    If[AssociationQ@makeFormRules@request["Body"], MapAt[makeFormRules, {2, "Body"}]@request, request]
]
```

Using it to process `HTTPRequest` received, the example code given in the question works.

```
request = MakeFormRules@ImportString[data, "HTTPRequest"];
```

It seems that WolframCloud use a function not provided in `CloudObject`(I didn't find it by `Names[something]`) but in its backend, which deals with this example and `multipart/formdata` etc.